# More than Key and values configuration

Tags: azure, appsettings

I'm want to move all my appsetting configuration to the configuration in Azure, buy I have config section more complex than key/value.
like this

```
  "AppMobileConfigurations": {
    "AndroidVersion": "1.2.3",
    "IosVersion": "1.2.3",
    "ForceUpdateEnable": "false"
  },
```

How can i put that configuration in this section of azure

[image: https://imgur.com/Od7XkD9]

Comment: like the answer mentions, add several keys\values. its supported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks should be like below.

[image]

[image]

For more details, you could refer to this [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2018/06/12/asp-net-core-settings-for-azure-app-service/).